# What does it refer to most general in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Which of the following types is the most general?

1

```
(Num a, Foldable t) => t a -> a
```

2

```
[Int] -> Int
```

3

```
(Num a) => [a] -> a
```

4

```
(Foldable t) => t Int -> Int
```

Can anyone explain why the answer is the first one? And what does it mean to have the most general type? Been doing some search online, didn't find anything useful!

Comment: Why do you think it i a different one?

Comment: Hint: how many things are to the left of `=>` and what do they mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is the first one, since the other ones are special cases of the first one.

## 2. `[Int] -> Int`

If we replace the `t` in the first signature with `[]` and the `a` with `Int`, we obtain:

```
[] Int -> Int
```

which is a more canonical form of:

```
[Int] -> Int
```

Since `[]` is an instance of the `Foldable` typeclass, and `Int` is an instance of the `Num` typeclass, we are allowed to specify the function in such way.

## 3. `Num a => [a] -> a`

Here we can replace `t` with `[]` to obtain as signature:

```
Num a => [a] -> a
```

## 4. `(Foldable t) => t Int -> Int`

Here we replace the `a` in the first signature with `Int`, and thus obtain:

```
(Foldable t) => t Int -> Int
```

Answer (score 3):

All that appears to be meant in this context is that the first actually includes all of the others, just by particular choices of `a` and/or `t`.

That first type:

```
(Num a, Foldable t) => t a -> a
```

means "a function that works for any `a` and `t`, provided that `a` is an instance of `Num` and `t` is an instance of `Foldable`".

In particular, if we specify that `t` is `[]` (the List type constructor, which is an instance of `Foldable`) and `a` is `Int` (which is an instance of `Num`), then we get

```
[Int] -> Int
```

which is exactly number 2. This shows that 1) is more general than 2), because when you have 1) you also necessarily have 2), but can't go in the other direction.

The other two cases are exactly the same, only they've only chosen a specific type for either `a` or `t`, but not both as 2) does.